# How can I disable or select a specific value in my selectbox with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have an input field:

```
<input id="count" name="count" min="1" value="1" type="number"  />
```

and a select box:

```
<select id="select">
    <option>nothing selected</option>
    <option data-number="4">four (4)</option>
    <option data-number="5">five (5)</option>
    <option data-number="6">six (6)</option>
</select>
```

I want to achieve the following:

If the input value of `#count` is higher than the `data-number` of `#select` then disable this option (for example: If input value of `#count` is higher than `"5"`then disable the option with `data-number="5"`.
And I would also like that automatically the option of `#select` is selected in which the value of `#count` fits best (for example: for input value `"3"` automatically select the opiton with `data-number "4"`, for input value `"4"` select opiton with `data-number "4"`, for input value `"5"` select opiton with `data-number "5"`)

This is how I tried to solve it, but it doesn't work:

```
$(function(){
            $('input').change(function(){
                if($('#count').val() > $('#select').data(number)) {
                    $('#select option').attr('disabled', true);
                }  
                else {
                    $('#select option').attr('disabled', false);
                } 
                if ($('#select').data(number) == Math.min($('#select').data(number) - $('#count').val()){
                   $('#select option').attr('selected', true);  
                }
            }); 
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dh1ak18t/

Comment: Your conditions are a little contradictory. You say _'If input value of #count is higher than "5"then disable the option with data-number="5"'_, but then later say _'for input value "5" select opiton with data-number "5"'_. So if 5 is selected in the input, should the select with data-number = 5 be selected, disabled, or both? This is what I came up with until you can clarify my question: https://jsfiddle.net/dh1ak18t/1/

Comment: Yes, if the input value is "5" then select option "5", but if input value is "6" then disable "5"

Comment: I looked at your fiddle, it is almost what I was looking for, thank you very much. It is just the other way arround. So if my input is "1" then "4" is selected and nothing is disabled. If my input is "2" then "4" is selected and nothing is disabled and so on. But if my input is "5" then "5" is selected and "4" is the only one disabled

Comment: Like this then: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dh1ak18t/2/?

Comment: Yes exactly! Perfect! Thank you so much. But how can I select your answer now as a right answer, if you only post it in the comment?

Comment: I tried your code with different values, do you know why it is not working anymore? https://jsfiddle.net/dh1ak18t/5/

Comment: This for example: https://jsfiddle.net/dh1ak18t/5/ And I tried to write into the input for example 46

Comment: Probably because it's not an exact match like in the first example. That's a slightly different problem than what you originally posted.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't explained it well. Actually I have bigger numbers, so that was what I meant with "value of  `#count` fits best", so 46 doesn't fit 40 so the system selects 50 because 46 fits in 50. But I will work now with your code and try to figure it out :)

Comment: OK, how about one more https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dh1ak18t/6/

Comment: Oh wow, you are so fast! Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry, I found one more little mistake in your new fiddle. If I input 40 it says "nothing selected"

Comment: Good catch. This fix it https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dh1ak18t/7/?

Comment: Yes, awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I was working with your code and I found something else. If I change the order of the options, it is not working anymore: https://jsfiddle.net/dh1ak18t/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$('input').change(function () {
    var that = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    $('#select option:gt(0)').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', ($(this).data('number') < that)).prop('selected', ($(this).data('number') >= that && $(this).prev().data('number') < that));
    })
    if (that <= $('#select option:eq(1)').data('number')) $('#select option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
}).change()
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dh1ak18t/9/)**

Comment: I tried to get your code work when I change the order of my options, but still I do not find the way how to do it

Answer (score 2):

check the below code and [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u564p01n/)

```
$('input').change(function(){
        if($('#count').val() > $('#select option:last-child()').data("number")) {
            $('#select option[data-number="6"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }  
        else {
            $('#select option[data-number="6"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#select option[data-number="'+$('#count').val()+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
        } 
    });
```

Comment: make it as answer if u like it

Comment: Nothing is disabled in the fiddle.

Comment: Same. Nothing is disabled. Is anything disabled for example if you have 5 in the input?

Comment: if it is higher than the data-number then only it will disable

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following code can help you.

```
 $(function() {

         $("#count").change(function() {

                    var countValue = parseInt($("#count").val());


                    $("#select option").each(function() {

                        var numberOption = parseInt($(this).attr("data-number"));
                        if (!isNaN(numberOption) && !isNaN(countValue) && countValue > numberOption)
                            $(this).hide();
                        else if (!isNaN(numberOption) && !isNaN(countValue))
                        {
                            $(this).show();


                        }

                        if (!isNaN(numberOption) && !isNaN(countValue) && countValue == numberOption)
                            $(this).attr("selected",true);

                    });


                });
            });
```